# mesa agents not work the function that put in Class Agents

Tags: python, mesa-abm

I try to put an function for the calcule of the venta "self.venta += 10" to verifique the model, but the result not change.

Someone can help me! thanks.

```
class MoneyAgent(mesa.Agent):

    def __init__(self, unique_id, model,row):
        super().__init__(unique_id, model)
        self.empresa = row[0]
        self.x_coord = row[1]
        self.y_coord = row[2]
        self.venta = int(row[3])
        self.empleado = int(row[4])
        self.zona = row[5]
        
        #defining the owners:
        self.owner = False
        if unique_id in model.owners:
            self.owner = True
            

    def step(self):
        self.venta += 10
```

**Not work the function for the increment of "venta", the result not change:**

```
     step  owner                                            empresa  x_coord  \
0    0.0    0.0                                            BELORTA    50.75   
1    0.0    0.0  SOCIETE INTERNATIONALE DE PLANTATIONS ET DE FI...    50.06   
2    0.0    1.0                                    PLUKON MOUSCRON    50.29   
3    0.0    1.0                                      SESVANDERHAVE    50.74   
4    0.0    1.0                        PLUIMVEESLACHTERIJ COOREMAN    50.98   
5    1.0    0.0                                            BELORTA    50.75   
6    1.0    0.0  SOCIETE INTERNATIONALE DE PLANTATIONS ET DE FI...    50.06   
7    1.0    1.0                                    PLUKON MOUSCRON    50.29   
8    1.0    1.0                                      SESVANDERHAVE    50.74   
9    1.0    1.0                        PLUIMVEESLACHTERIJ COOREMAN    50.98
```

```
    y_coord   venta  empleado  
0      3.40  5900.0      50.0  
1      4.63  1500.0      10.0  
2      5.82  5000.0      45.0  
3      4.70  2500.0      25.0  
4      4.97  1000.0       1.0  
5      3.40  5900.0      50.0  
6      4.63  1500.0      10.0  
7      5.82  5000.0      45.0  
8      4.70  2500.0      25.0  
9      4.97  1000.0       1.0
```

Comment: the shown data are `MoneyAgent` instance or `row` ?

Answer (score 0):

the poblema is resolved, i forget code to run "model.step()"
for i in range(3):
model.step()
for agent in model.schedule.agents:
if isinstance(agent, MoneyAgent):
farm_empresa.append([i, agent.empresa])
farm_x_coord.append([i, agent.x_coord])
farm_y_coord.append([i, agent.y_coord])
farm_venta.append([i, agent.venta])
farm_empleado.append([i, agent.empleado])
farm_zona.append([i, agent.zona])
farm_owner.append([i, agent.owner])

step  owner                                            empresa  x_coord  
0    0.0    0.0                                            BELORTA    50.75
1    0.0    1.0  SOCIETE INTERNATIONALE DE PLANTATIONS ET DE FI...    50.06
2    0.0    0.0                                    PLUKON MOUSCRON    50.29
3    0.0    1.0                                      SESVANDERHAVE    50.74
4    0.0    1.0                        PLUIMVEESLACHTERIJ COOREMAN    50.98
5    1.0    0.0                                            BELORTA    50.75
6    1.0    1.0  SOCIETE INTERNATIONALE DE PLANTATIONS ET DE FI...    50.06
7    1.0    0.0                                    PLUKON MOUSCRON    50.29
8    1.0    1.0                                      SESVANDERHAVE    50.74
9    1.0    1.0                        PLUIMVEESLACHTERIJ COOREMAN    50.98

```
y_coord   venta  empleado
```

0      3.40  5910.0      50.0
1      4.63  1510.0      10.0
2      5.82  5010.0      45.0
3      4.70  2510.0      25.0
4      4.97  1010.0       1.0
5      3.40  5920.0      50.0
6      4.63  1520.0      10.0
7      5.82  5020.0      45.0
8      4.70  2520.0      25.0
9      4.97  1020.0       1.0